# PortfolioAnalytics and regime switching issue

Tags: programming, portfolio-optimization, market-regimes

I've been playing around with the R package PortfolioAnalytics and I have spent more time than I'm willing to admit to try and resolve this issue:

When I follow the regime switching example with the edhec data from the vignette (https://gist.github.com/rossb34/10328671) the code picks the 2 different individual regimes and it works, but if I use my data set, the single portfolio optimisations on each regime seem to be using only one of the regimes. The same issue happens if I randomly generate some data. I think it's perhaps something to do with the xts object, but I really have no idea. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the code with random data, at the end running "opt1\$regime" and "opt2\$regime" gives the same number instead of 1 and 2, respectively:

```
library(PortfolioAnalytics)

set.seed(123)
obs <- matrix(rnorm(2680)/100,,10)

dates <- seq(as.Date("1999-02-01"), length = 268, by = "months")
dates

data<-xts(x = obs, order.by = dates)
colnames(data)<-c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j")

R<-data

set.seed(123)
regime <- xts(sample(1:2, nrow(R), replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.3, 0.7)), index(R))

port1 <- portfolio.spec(assets=colnames(R))
port1 <- add.constraint(port1, "weight_sum", min_sum=0.99, max_sum=1.01)
port1 <- add.constraint(port1, "box", min=0.1, max=0.5)
port1 <- add.objective(port1, type="risk", name="ES", arguments=list(p=0.9))
port1 <- add.objective(port1, type="risk_budget", name="ES", arguments=list(p=0.9), max_prisk=0.5)

#' Construct portfolio for regime 2.
port2 <- portfolio.spec(assets=colnames(R))
port2 <- add.constraint(port2, "weight_sum", min_sum=0.99, max_sum=1.01)
port2 <- add.constraint(port2, "box", min=0, max=0.6)
port2 <- add.objective(port2, type="risk", name="StdDev")
port2 <- add.objective(port2, type="risk_budget", name="StdDev", max_prisk=0.5)

#' Combine the portfolios.
portfolios <- combine.portfolios(list(port1, port2))

#' Now we construct the regime model and corresponding portfolios to use for
#' each regime.
regime.port <- regime.portfolios(regime, portfolios)

regime.port

#' This optimization should result in out portfolio for regime 1, but it picks regime 2.
opt1 <- optimize.portfolio(R, regime.port, 
                           optimize_method="random", 
                           search_size=200, 
                           trace=TRUE)
opt1
opt1$regime

#' This optimization should result in out portfolio for regime 2, this one picks regime 2 as well.
opt2 <- optimize.portfolio(R[1:(nrow(R)-1)], regime.port, 
                           optimize_method="random", 
                           search_size=200, 
                           trace=TRUE)
opt2
opt2$regime
```

Answer (score 1):

https://gist.github.com/rossb34/10328671 differs in the portfolios passed as arguments in the different steps. Do try it that way and report. Essentially, it says:

```r
  portfolio <- list(port1, port2)
  # ...
  opt_regime <- regime.backtest(R, portfolio, regime, ...)
  # ...
  opt_port1 <- optimize.portfolio.rebalancing(R, port1, ...)
  opt_port2 <- optimize.portfolio.rebalancing(R, port2, ...)
```

So in your code, try after changing the following way:

```r
  opt1 <- optimize.portfolio(... port1 ...) # instead of regime.port
  opt2 <- optimize.portfolio(... port2 ...) # instead of regime.port
```